# Changes Images folder, based on time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeofday

Update - Already caught one issue. Was simply my stupid mistake. 
How do I add a function to make this code rerun itself for each time block, so it updates on an open browser? - Thanks

I am trying to have a simple gallery of images (For example 20 images, 15 sec each, scrolling indefinitely), but all the images will change based on the time of day. For example: 8am-11am one set, 12pm-4pm another, 4-8pm, and 8pm-7am. 
I have been messing with this from existing code I have found, and tried a ton of versions, but none have worked.

This is the code idea I am messing with (not working), but maybe I should be going about this entirely differently. Thoughts?

(example of different time blocks, and only with 3 images - but doesn't work)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

// If time is after 8PM or before 7AM
if (n > 20 || n < 7) {
$("img#photo1").attr("src","img/8TO7/photo1.jpg");
$("img#photo2").attr("src","img/8TO7/photo2.jpg");
$("img#photo3").attr("src","img/8TO7/photo3.jpg");
}

else if (n > 16 && n < 20) {
 $("img#photo1").attr("src","img/4TO8/photo1.jpg");
 $("img#photo2").attr("src","img/4TO8/photo2.jpg");
 $("img#photo3").attr("src","img/4TO8/photo3.jpg");
 }

else {
 $("img#photo1").attr("src","img/main/photo1.jpg");
 $("img#photo2").attr("src","img/main/photo2.jpg");
 $("img#photo3").attr("src","img/main/photo3.jpg");
 }
});
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Do you get any errors in your browser's console? One issue I see is that there are some funky quotes in your code: `“` vs `"`.

Comment: Try to be more specific than "doesn't work". Specific error messages or descriptions of observed behavior will help.

Comment: If you can provide the corresponding HTML, that will help. (p.s., when using id's, you don't need the tag name. So "img#photo1" can just be "#photo1".)

Comment: Showdev - I see the quotes.. and fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Dave - Thanks for the info on not needing the tag. I will switch that. Appreciated.

Comment: Thanks skrrgwasme, I will try to be more specific.  I think showdevs catch on the quotes helped.

Comment: It seems to be working, but will it change automatically will it changes into the next block? Or do I need it to run again at certain times?

Comment: @Fatty you need to use setInterval

Answer (score 1):

The following demo should do what you want.

You can re-run your code with `setIntervall(callback, time_in_ms)`. In the demo the interval is set to 5sec. to show that it is running.

Maybe you could add image caching and a check that the images are only reloaded if necessary. At the moment, it reloads the images at every callback.

You can find the same code here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/2eLk4dL1/).

For testing you can pass a time to `var d = new Date('17/12/2014 16:00:00');` so it's easier to test that the right set is displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //var d = new Date();
    
    var timer = function () {
        var d = new Date(); //'17/12/2014 06:00:00'); // test date 4pm to 8pm  
        console.log(d);
        var n = d.getHours();
        console.log(n);

        var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/';
        var urls8pmto7am = [url + '1/', url + '2/', url + '3/'];
        var urls4pmto8m = [url + '4/', url + '5/', url + '6/'];
        var urls = [url + '7/', url + '8/', url + '9/'];

        // If time is after 8PM or before 7AM
        if (n > 20 || n < 7) {
            console.log('show set 8pm to 7am');
            $("#photo1").attr("src", urls8pmto7am[0]);
            $("#photo2").attr("src", urls8pmto7am[1]);
            $("#photo3").attr("src", urls8pmto7am[2]);
        } else if (n >= 16 && n <= 20) {

            console.log('show set 4pm to 8pm');
            $("#photo1").attr("src", urls4pmto8m[0]);
            $("#photo2").attr("src", urls4pmto8m[1]);
            $("#photo3").attr("src", urls4pmto8m[2]);
        } else { // main

            console.log('else, should not be triggered');
            $("#photo1").attr("src", urls[0]);
            $("#photo2").attr("src", urls[1]);
            $("#photo3").attr("src", urls[2]);
        }
    };
    
    timer(); // run immediatly after start
    
    setInterval(timer, 5 *1000); // 1 *1000 *60 *60 runs every hour for testing every 5 seconds
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" id="photo1" />
<img src="" id="photo2" />
<img src="" id="photo3" />
```

Comment: Is this code below simply adding a "1" to the url:    var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/';
        var urls8pmto7am = [url + '1/', url + '2/', url + '3/'];
        var urls4pmto8m = [url + '4/', url + '5/', url + '6/'];
        var urls = [url + '7/', url + '8/', url + '9/'];

Comment: and the 4to8 the files are numbered 4 through 6? is that right here? Just trying to figure how to get that to work for me.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask my question is, why is there 3 urls for each one? Ex:  var urls8pmto7am = [url + '1/', url + '2/', url + '3/'];

Comment: that is just string appending. url is `http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/` and if you type in your browser [http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1](http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1) you'll see the image. If you have the file locally you can do something like `url='img/photo';` and append `1.jpg`. Also you can write the full url into the array. It was just easier with the long url.